# display fetched data from API does not work - Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular8, ngfor

I'm new to Angular and I still don't understand very well how it works.
I fetched data from a API I built. It works because I tested it in postman.
I can't display them in my angular app, and I don't get why.

My *api.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  private SERVER_URL  = 'http://localhost:8080/returnShelf';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public get() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.SERVER_URL);
  }


}
```

My *home.component.ts*:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  books = [];
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.apiService.get().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.books = data;
        });
  }

}
```

my *home.component.html*:

```
<div style="padding: 13px;">

  <div *ngFor="let book of books">
    <h2>{{book.title}}</h2>

      <p>
        {{book.author}}
      </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Can somebody explain why I still can't display my books data?

Comment: what do you see in the browser developer tools? on network tab is the request sent out? console.log prints something in the console?

Comment: Probably a cors issue. Look at the browser's debugging tools

Comment: The console: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:8080/returnShelf. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)"

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed tho

Comment: can you try this   public get() {
    return this.httpClient.jsonp(this.SERVER_URL);
  } ...... insted of   public get() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.SERVER_URL);
  }

Answer (score 0):

*Ok*, I had a look around internet and the problem is that my back-end is not mapping CORS.

**the solution consisted of adding in the ApiApplication.java a corsConfigurer, this way:**

```
 @Bean
        public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
                @Override
                public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                }
            };
        }
```

Thanks everyone for the support!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
create proxy.conf.json file in src folder and add the following content:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

Next, open the angular.json file and add a proxyConfig key under the serve->options that points to the src/proxy.conf.json file as follows:

```
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
  ...
  }
}
```